# PrestaShop no save product

Tags: prestashop

PrestaShop 1.6.1.3 no save items.
On product admin page I have this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: countDown is not defined
at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:3:2)
at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at e.fn.init.n.fn.ready (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:2:13)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
at Function.globalEval (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at e.fn.init.domManip (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3)
at e.fn.init.append (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3)
```

and buttons:

[image]

**I try:**

1. Do this: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/5566c2d9d7e4ab88a201b2c5cf10e1cda2ff7150/admin-dev/themes/default/template/controllers/products/helpers/form/form.tpl#L252-L254
   delete

   ```
                   submitHandler: function(form) {
                   form.submit();
               },
   ```
2. send second time admin.js file

Still Buttons do not work, any know why? :)

Comment: Try to disable non-prestashop plugins on adminstrations > performances.

See what's happen?

Comment: when you look under "network" tab on chrome console you can see which tab is failed loaded, then note the url and active errors and reload this url to see errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you may have a JS error preventing the script to load correctly.

Also a bad module configuration may be preventing the tab loading and if all tabs are not loaded and the buttons won't stop spinning.

I'd suggest to disable the non native modules in the Advanced Parameters > Performance and check the product edit page again.

If it works then you may disable the option and disable the latest modules you may have installed.

Then activate them one by one and check the edit page every time to find the culprit.